# invalid EFI file path on windows 8

Tags: installation, dual-boot, uefi

I installed ubuntu 13.04 on my new notebook (that came with windows 8 installed) and now when I try to load windows 8 appear the error:

> impossible to find command 'drivemap'. (this is in portuguese, I'm not sure if I translated it right
>
> invalid EFI file path.

ubuntu is working OK. someone knows what can I do to solve this and have both SO running? I have searched on the internet but couldn't find anything I could understand. can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I recommend you go into your firmware and disable Secure Boot, if you haven't already done so. This isn't always required, but Secure Boot seems to cause a lot of problems with many Ubuntu installations, so IMHO it's best to disable it. This will *not* solve the specific problem you're reporting, though.

Second, do *one* of the following things:

- In Linux, install my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). There's a Debian package that you can install quite easily. The result is that when you reboot, you should see rEFInd rather than GRUB. rEFInd should enable you to boot Windows or Linux (and to boot Linux either directly or via GRUB).
- In Linux, install and run the Ubuntu [Boot Repair tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). This should fix your problem, but it will probably leave stray and non-functional boot entries. Some users find that it doesn't create bootable Windows entries, but it does for others.

If you try Boot Repair first and it doesn't work to your satisfaction, be sure to run it again and restore the backup files it created before trying rEFInd. There's an option in the advanced menu of Boot Repair to restore its backup files.

Comment: I disabled Secure Boot before installing windows. What solution do you think I should try first?

Comment: Whichever sounds better to you, based on those descriptions. My own preference would be rEFInd, but as I maintain it, I'm biased.

Comment: The boot repair tool worked fine for me.