# dual boot lost, how can I enter in ubuntu again?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I have a notebook and, while in windows 8, a updater software that came with it updated the bios and now I can only access windows. how can I restore the boot options?
my note has UEFI and I had some problems with dual boot with it. the problem can be seen in this question: [invalid EFI file path on windows 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297431/invalid-efi-file-path-on-windows-8)
someone knows how can I restore the dual boot with windows 8 and ubutu?
sory if my english is bad.

Comment: Your bios update erased the NVRAM entry for linux, I think you could reinstall rEFInd from Windows, as in this [procedure](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#windows), in case you don't want to chroot into your linux from a Live CD and reinstall from there.

Comment: Can I install the binary Debian package from ubuntu running it in the CD without problems? I don't have any experience installing things manually and I fear I would make some bad mistake...

Answer (score 1):

Three options spring to mind:

- Installing [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) as Mike C. has already suggested. This will probably work fairly easily to get access to Linux via GRUB. Once you've booted Linux via GRUB, you can optionally install an EFI filesystem driver and run the `mkrlconf.sh` script to create a configuration file that will enable booting Linux without using GRUB, if you care to go that route. This last isn't absolutely required, though.
- Using the Windows `bcdedit` command to re-activate GRUB as the default boot loader. A command like `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`, typed in an Administrator Command Prompt window, should do the trick.
- Using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to fix the problem automatically. Unfortunately, Boot Repair is a bit heavy-handed in its approach (it tries every fix the developers could conceive of simultaneously), so one side effect is that there's usually an explosion of options in the GRUB menu. To avoid this, access the Advanced Options menu and uncheck the Backup and Rename EFI Files option.

Note that the first two options require extra effort or variations if you're booting with Secure Boot enabled, so if you want to try either of those, you should disable Secure Boot (if it's enabled).

Comment: Since Erik said in a comment that he's basically not familiar with doing risky tasks at the command line, I would go with option #2 in a script to be run as Administrator, script that should check the existence of \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi in ESP and all other prerequisites, before setting {bootmgr}. Which option do you consider the safest for him?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Used Super Grub Disk to load Windows (you’ll have option to choose from available OSs.)
2. Turned Fast Boot off. See elsewhere for instructions.
3. Turned Restore off.  See elsewhere for instructions.
4. Type the following command in a command prompt with Admin privilege:

   ```
   bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
   ```
5. Always Shut Down Windows, not Restart.