# after installing ubuntu, can't start windows

Tags: 13.04, boot, grub2, windows-8, boot-repair

After a difficult installation of ubuntu on a win 8 asus n56v, now I only can get ubuntu running... On starting computer I get different options including some win 8 (eg on sda2). I tried boot repair but didnt work. after choosing win8 i get message: "cant find command drive map" and "invalid efi file path".
more info:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6112607
and here:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6114637

thanks, yoeri

Comment: So what happened when you picked the win8 option from the grub menu

Comment: message: "cant find command drive map" and "invalid efi file path"

Comment: Does this answer help you http://askubuntu.com/a/297436/71679

Comment: extra info that might help: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6114637 . Thanks for the other suggestion, Damien. I get a warning though when I want to install the deb of refind...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting into windows without using grub? If you have an option to access UEFI have you tried booting from there? Try booting the recovery partition. I don't know why, but in the past the one that said recovery was actually my primary os. If that one doesn't work, try each of the listed efi's one at a time using the entry that looks like this:

```
menuentry "Windows UEFI bkpbootmgfw.efi" {
set root='(hd1,gpt1)'
chainloader /EFI/microsoft/BOOT/bkpbootmgfw.efi
```

}

If that one doesn't work, change bpkbootmgfw.efi to bootmgfw.efi and try that one.

Comment: Tried, but no: invalid efi path.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what finally did it: reinstall of windows 8!